# How to reference KML file on my pc instead of any server online, in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, kml, fetch, google-earth

I have web application with Google Earth embedded but so far its not doing anything. What I need is to "reference"/parse a KML file to it which I created on my pc and load it up in the application.

I used some java script codes from Google where KML file is fetched but if I get it right it is taking it from sketchup.google.com/.

So can I do the same but with my own KML file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [KML mime types for your web server](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/faq.html#mimetypes)

Just follow the Google maps examples, and with your server set to handle KML mime types correctly you can host your own KML's

Comment: What do you mean by my web server. Can I use my localhost for this?

Comment: Well .. yeah sorry
What I have so far is a web application in asp.net, c# and database behind in MySQL. One of the features is a graphical representation of a project i.e in Google Earth. I have a GPS cordinates in my database as a column (lat and long) and I was wondering if I need to get these coordinates and convert to KML and then "reference" this KML into my web application. 
That't the whole idea and I don't really know where to start from :(
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Pepys SO is for programming problems, other than that read the Google documentation?